# How to enlarge boxplot in tickzpicture

Tags: bar-chart, bar

I've got a question about a barplot using tikz. I' m not very used to tikz and I'm trying to learn how to use it for my thesis. I give you my code. I'd like to enlarge the box so the "90" over "Spagna" seems less near. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
Paese & carT \\
Spagna     & 90   \\
Italia     & 47  \\
Francia    & 12 \\
Portogallo   & 9 \\
Germania   & 7   \\
Belgio      & 4  \\
Paesi Bassi & 4 \\
Lussemburgo & 1\\
}\mydata

\begin{figure}
\caption{Numero di Cartolarizzazioni SME ABS presenti nel database}
\label{ED:cartSME}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
symbolic x coords={Spagna,Italia,Francia,Portogallo,Germania,Belgio,Paesi 
Bassi,Lussemburgo},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
x tick label style= {rotate=90,anchor=east}
]
\addplot[fill=black!40] table[x=Paese,y=carT]{\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the maximum value of the y-axis with the key `ymax`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
  Paese       & carT \\
  Spagna      & 90   \\
  Italia      & 47   \\
  Francia     & 12   \\
  Portogallo  & 9    \\
  Germania    & 7    \\
  Belgio      & 4    \\
  Paesi Bassi & 4    \\
  Lussemburgo & 1    \\
}\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={Spagna,Italia,Francia,Portogallo,Germania,Belgio,Paesi 
      Bassi,Lussemburgo},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    x tick label style= {rotate=90,anchor=east},
    ymax = 110,
    ]
    \addplot[fill=black!40] table[x=Paese,y=carT]{\mydata};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]